# Timeout issue in AWS Route53 Domain

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am pretty new about AWS and admin setup.

I signed up for AWS Route53 DNS yesterday and I setup Elastic IP, Security Group and etc about everything for DNS.

BTW, I installed nginx for a web server.

However, **I am in trouble to get the default webpage through Domain Name.** IP is OK, by the way. I double checked NameServr in registered domain and everything are same as hostedzon. And I set up "A" with name : joxxxx.com and my elastic IP address.

Would you please help me? The followings are what I got from the test but I do not know what is the root issue and what should I do further to fix the issue.
Thank you!

From my SSH with Ubuntu

with Private IP :

```
ubuntu@ip-172.xxx.xxx.xxx:/usr/bin$ dig @172.3x.xx.xxx ec2.amazonaws.com

; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Ubuntu <<>> @172.3x.xx.xxx ec2.amazonaws.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

with Elastic IP

```
; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Ubuntu <<>> @18.2x.xx.xxx ec2.amazonaws.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

ubuntu@ip-172.xxx.xx.xx.xx:/$ sudo /sbin/route -n

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         172.xxx.xxx.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
172.xx.xx.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.240.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

ubuntu@ip-172-xxx.xxx.xxx:/$ sudo /sbin/iptables -nL
    Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
    target     prot opt source               destination

```
Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

ubuntu@ip-172.xxx.xxx.xxx:/$ sudo /sbin/iptables -t mangle -nL

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

From http://www.kloth.net

```
 <<>> DiG 9 <<>> @localhost jooxxxxxxx.com A
 ; (1 server found)
 ;; global options: +cmd
 ;; Got answer:
 ;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 15xxxx
 ;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

 ;; QUESTION SECTION:
 ;jooxxxx.xx.           IN  A

 ;; ANSWER SECTION:
 joonseoan.xx.      60  IN  A   18.xxx.xx.xxx

 ;; Query time: 27 msec
 ;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
 ;; WHEN: Sat Sep  8 19:29:17 2018
 ;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 47
```

Comment: [DNS updates can last up to 72h](https://www.pickaweb.co.uk/kb/why-propagation-delay-occures-and-causes-inaccessibility-of-website/)

Comment: @ComputerVersteher - DNS updates are based upon the TTL which can be much shorter or much longer than 72 hours.

Comment: Why would you `dig @x.x.x.x`?  That doesn't make sense based on the information in the question.

Comment: Thanks, all. Hi Michael. I tied to do that in an instruction in AWS. Someone had a same issue so I just followed the instruction there. Actually, i do not have any idea for that. ^^;;